# How to get rid of the warning: Implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value

Tags: c++, xcode, 32bit-64bit, compiler-warnings, implicit-conversion

First of all, I am a beginner in c++ and I am using Xcode 4.6.2. The compiler configuration is  default. I only switched the the compiler to gcc 4.2.
If I compile my little code I get the following warnings:

> Implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
>    Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'unsigned int'

and this is the code, which triggers the warnings:

```
median = temps[temps.size()/2];
```

**Hint:** temps is a vector of double, and median is a double

What I have to do to get rid of these warnings ? Is it possible to handle this by compiler configuration (I do not mean disabling the warnings ;-) )or do I have to change my code ?

Comment: That warning doesn't make sense for the line you posted. Try showing the warning including the exact ranges that Xcode highlights.

Answer (score 1):

`temps.size()` returns (from what I can read) an unsigned long, yet `2` is an (unsigned)int.

try

```
temps[(unsigned long)temps.size()/(unsigned long)2]
```

or

```
temps[(unsigned long)((unsigned long)temps.size()/(unsigned long)2)]
```

Comment: I'm not certain this is right, since `2` would be promoted to an unsigned long.  I think the error is the _next_ step, where `operator[]` is expecting an `int` instead of an `unsigned long`

Comment: @MooingDuck or maybe that, I thought about it but was something like "nah".., we will see what the OPs' feeback will be. Would be a-logical to have a negative index :o

Comment: We already have feedback: "loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'unsigned int'"

Answer (score 0):

Under the project settings go the the section 'LLVM GCC 4.2 - warnings' or the sections that is appropriate for your compiler and select 'inhibit all warnings'

Comment: Surely you *want* the warnings on! They're letting you know when something is happening that isn't right or (possibly) isn't what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

No, I had been facing the same issue  in X-CODE with the above mentioned compiler "Apple LLVM Compiler 4.2" and it got solved by using "unsigned long int" instead of "int" data type...